# How do I use actionListeners without JButtons?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I was reading the documentation on swing timers, when I came across some information about `ActionListener`s. When further researched, all I could find is how to create an `ActionListener` attached to a `JButton`, etc. How can you create a plain `ActionListener`, not attached to anything?

My timer is not working correctly, and I thought it may be because I was incorrectly using the `ActionListener`.

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class MyTimer {

    ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            System.out.println("testing");
        }
    };

    public MyTimer() {

        Timer timer = new Timer(10, al);
        timer.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyTimer start = new MyTimer();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can you create a plain actionlistner, not attached to anything?

Loot at this:

```
ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
};

// Using the listener with 2 seconds delay
java.swing.Timer timer = new java.swing.Timer(2000, listener);
timer.setRepeats(false);

// Start the timer
timer.start();
```

---

Try with this:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.Timer;

public class MyTimer {
    ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            System.out.println("testing");
        }
    };

    public MyTimer() {
        Timer timer = new Timer(1000, al);
        timer.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                 new MyTimer();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: how can I start the timer?

Answer (score 3):

An `ActionListener` is just an `interface`

You can create an stand alone version by implementing it and then instanstanting it....

```
public class MyActionHandler implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        // do something...
    }
}
```

And sometime in the future...

```
MyActionHandler handler = new MyActionHandler();
```

Or you could create an anonymous instance....

```
ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        // do something...
    }
};
```

Take a look at [Interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html) for more details

Comment: Your code seems to work fine for me.  What problems are you having?